Fetch API gives ENOTFOUND error in Next.js 14 Server component running on Kubernetes, but works with Axios
I'm currently working on a Next.js application running on a Kubernetes cluster. I'm trying to make a GET request to https://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local/api/users/currentUser using the Fetch API, but I'm encountering an ENOTFOUND error. The error message is as follows:
Error: HTTP error! status: 404
Interestingly, when I switch to using Axios for the same request, it works perfectly fine. I'm not sure why this is happening. Is there a difference in how Fetch and Axios handle requests in a Kubernetes environment? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.
const fetchUser = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local/api/users/currentUser",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
          Host: "ticketing.dev",
        },
      }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log("data", data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error*****", error);
  }
};```





